# Hadoop: mkdir: failed to create /user

Tags: java, linux, hadoop

I am following this document https://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module2.html

for learning the concepts of Hadoop.

When I execute the following command:

```
bin/hadoop dfs -mkdir /user
```

I get the following output:

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar 
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar 
mkdir: failed to create /user
```

Could you please let me know how to rectify this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong syntax.

Use either 
`hdfs dfs -mkdir <directory_name>`(preferrably) or `hadoop fs -mkdir <directory_name>`.